# Error (Run-time error 5) will not raise when "On error resume next" is active

Tags: vba, error-handling, runtime, runtime-error

I've provided the actual code I'm using below.
The exact condition I'm trying to handle is the `strCurrentRev` argument as a zero-length string.  (e.g. `strCurrentRev=""`)

If I comment out the error handling statements, trying to execute the ASC method on a zero-length string throws `Run-Time Error 5` for "invalid procedure call or argument".
If I then check `err.Number` it's = 5.

If I try to run the exact same statement with `on error resume next` active, it will not raise any errors, e.g. after execution `err.number` is always = 0.

If `on error resume next` is active, and you try to execute the ASC method from the immediate window (e.g. Type `asc(strcurrentrev)` and hit `Enter`) it will throw the run-time error and set the `err.number` property to 5.

I've never experienced this before.  Why would having `on error resume next` active cause the error not to raise in normal execution???

```
Function NextRevLetter(strCurrentRev As String) As String
'This function returns the next revision letter given an existing revision letter.

'Declare variables
    Dim lngX As Long
    Dim strX As String
    Dim strY As String

'First, check if we are dealing with rev A-Z or AA-ZZ
        If Len(strCurrentRev) <= 1 Then
        'Check that we can work with revision letter ***THIS IS WHERE I AM HAVING A PROBLEM!***
            On Error Resume Next
            Err.Clear
            'Procedure call to flag errors with ASC method without changing any values
                lngX=Asc(strCurrentRev) 
                lngX=0
            On Error GoTo 0
                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                    Err.Clear
                        If Len(strCurrentRev) < 1 Then
                        'No revision specified, assign first revision"
                            strCurrentRev = "-"
                        Else
                            MsgBox "The revision letter specified is not compliant.  The next revision letter cannot be determined.", vbOKOnly, "Error: Revision does not follow rules"
                        'Return the existing revision (no change) and exit function
                            NextRevLetter = strCurrentRev
                            Exit Function
                        End If
                End If

            'Code continues - not important for this question...
Exit Function
```

Comment: Hint: *no error* will ever be raised when `On Error Resume Next` is active.. it's the purpose of the instruction! Avoid it unless you know what you're doing ;-)

Comment: @Mat's Mug, your comment is incorrect.  Errors  *ARE* still raised with `On Error Resume Next` active, however this statement tells the run-time environment to ignore the error and continue execution.

Comment: of course it's raised and you can check for `Err.Number`. But for the common of mortals it's perhaps easier to understand that `On Error Resume Next` is shoving runtime errors under the carpet - and that's in no way an incorrect statement.

Comment: No, that is not incorrect.  But saying that "no error will ever be raised" is incorrect.  As you just clarified, the error's are still there, just being ignored.  But, using an `On Error Resume Next` loop like above is about the best way to trap and handle specific errors differently in VBA, so saying to just ignore the statement entirely I think is not great advice either.  Using it to get dirty code to run=bad, using it for error handling=powerful tool

Comment: Ummmm. No. No it is not the best way to trap and handle specific errors differently. Not at all. No no no no no.

Comment: @CBRF23 I agree it's a "powerful tool" - and *with great power comes great responsibilities*. The first thing to do is to [avoid executing code that can fail in known ways](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30106010/1188513) in the first place.

Comment: @RubberDuck - Could you elaborate? Why is it not at all the best method?  What other ways would you recommend for trapping and handling errors in VBA?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not using the right tool for the job. Runtime errors should be *handled*, not *shoved under the carpet* (because that's what `On Error Resume Next` does - execution happily continues as if nothing happened).

You need to try to *avoid* raising that error in the first place. What's causing it?

```
lngX=Asc(strCurrentRev)
```

You already know what's happening:

> *The exact condition I'm trying to handle is the strCurrentRev argument as a zero-length string.*

Well then, the correct way to handle this is to verify the length of `strCurrentRev` *before* you pass it to the `Asc` function, which *you know* will raise a runtime error #5 if you give it an empty string!

```
If strCurrentRev <> vbNullString Then
    'calling Asc(strCurrentRev) here will not fail!
End If
```

Comment: I disagree that this is the "wrong tool for the job".  This function is accessed from countless (well at least more than I care to guess at right now) projects, so having to sort through and add additional code in the calling procedure is waste of time, and we all know redundant code is a maintenance issue.  I'm handling the error not shoving it under the rug - check error number, do something to handle it.  This was made obsolete by Try/Catch in .NET, but in VBA this about the best way to do it if you want to *handle* specific errors at the root level procedure.

Comment: Also, if you use VBA for Solidworks at all (which maybe you don't) a lot of the interop objects have no way of checking the return of a procedure call so you cannot check the value before attempting to access the object.  This necessitates the use of what I fondly call a "ghetto try/catch" loop as I've shown above.  Not saying this is the applicable in all situations, but I think it's a little presumptuous to just assume what is or isn't the right choice for the job without having any details of the project.

Comment: Also, not to continue this discussion - but while I was specifically trying to handle a zero-length string, the error is thrown by other non-ASC characters that may be pulled from the database that passes the arguments.  Sorry that was not clear in the original question, but is the reason I didn't want to check just for length.  Your solution is valid for the way my question was worded!

Comment: Well then, short of avoiding avoidable errors, the correct way to handle them in VBA is to jump to an error-handling subroutine with `On Error GoTo [label]`, handle the error, and if the error is recoverable to resume with a `Resume Next` instruction - inlining error handling with `Resume Next` is a dirty way of going about it - you're intertwining the procedure's logic with error-handling, which obscures the intent of the code.

Comment: Agree to disagree.  I don't think there's anything "dirty" about using `Resume Next` to try and execute a specific line, immediately going back to `GoTo 0`, and then checking the result.  This is just one way to do `Try/Catch` in VBA.

Comment: As for intent - I find code with lots of `GoTo` statements a LOT more difficult to interpret when I jump into someone elses project.   Handling errors in-line I find very easy to understand the intent.  Often I'll use a "try" like above and then have a select case based on the error number.  It's easy to read.  Try reading 6 different `GoTo`'s for all the different possible error numbers.  I think it's more difficult.  If you need to do really complex error handling you can create a procedure (or error handler class) and call it inline to handle your errors.  This is also easy to read IMHO.

Comment: There's lot of things dirty about `On Error Resume Next`. Chip Pearson called it "The most abused feature of VBA" and he was right. I posted an alternative solution for you below. It doesn't swallow all of the errors that we're not expecting. Just handles the one we are.

Comment: @CBRF23 Don't get me wrong - I hardly ever use a `GoTo` statement. I cordially invite you to bring some of that working code over to [codereview.se] (including more of the context code of course), I'm sure a full-blown code review Q&A of the procedure in its full glory (or the whole module even!) would be much more useful than this little comment discussion.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I had never seen Code Review before.  Very cool.  I will post some projects over there when I get them closer.  This project is still in rough stages of development and I don't get enough time to work on it to clean it up right now.  I have a few modules I know could be better and would love some input!!

Comment: I posted an example on Code Review.  [Link to Post](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/90738/what-is-the-best-way-to-handle-try-catch-in-vb6).  I have an older project (larger scale) that I created an error handling class that I could call from any module that worked really well - but I don't have that on this computer and don't have time to dig through archived project right now at home.

Answer (score 2):

I was asked to elaborate on a better way to handle the error, and this is the easiest place to do so. I think it's okay, because in a way it does answer the original question as well. However, let me say first that the right thing to do here is to avoid the error entirely, but for the sake of completeness, there is a way to do this *cleanly* with an error handler.

The idea is to check the error number, handle it by fixing the value, and *then* resuming the next line of code.

```
Function NextRevLetter(strCurrentRev As String) As String
'This function returns the next revision letter given an existing revision letter.

On Error GoTo ErrHandler

'Declare variables
    Dim lngX As Long
    Dim strX As String
    Dim strY As String

'First, check if we are dealing with rev A-Z or AA-ZZ
    If Len(strCurrentRev) <= 1 Then

        'Procedure call to flag errors with ASC method without changing any values
        lngX = Asc(strCurrentRev)
        lngX = 0

        'Code continues - not important for this question...

    End If

Exit Function

ErrHandler:
    If Err.Number = 5 Then
        lngX = 0
        If Len(strCurrentRev) < 1 Then
        'No revision specified, assign first revision"
            strCurrentRev = "-"
            Resume Next
        Else
            MsgBox "The revision letter specified is not compliant.  The next revision letter cannot be determined.", vbOKOnly, "Error: Revision does not follow rules"
            'Return the existing revision (no change) and exit function
            NextRevLetter = strCurrentRev
            Exit Function
        End If

    Else If Err.Number = someOtherExpectedError        
        'handle it appropriately

    Else
        ' !!! This is important.
        ' If we come across an error we don't know how to handle, we re-raise it.
        Err.Raise Err.Number, Err.Source, Err.Description
    End If

End Function
```

Note that the flow of your program is not interrupted by all of this error handling and we only handle the error that we're expecting. So, if an error is raised, we recover *only if we know how to*. Otherwise, execution is halted.

I would still prefer just to check to see if the value is `= vbNullString` though.

Answer (score 1):

I just figured this out.  The `On Error GoTo 0` statement resets the `Err.Number` property to 0.

Sorry for wasting anyones time!!!!

Comment: You should be aware that *any* `On Error` statement will `Clear` the global `Err` object.

Comment: @RubberDuck, I don't program everyday so sometimes I forget these basic things. I would have deleted the question but thought it might help someone else who stumbles across it, since I asked it only when I couldn't find an answer to my question searching.  Maybe I was searching for the wrong terms, but I just thought it could help someone down the line.

Comment: It's actually not a very basic thing. This very morning I was confused about the same issue in my own code. I'm sure this question will help some one down the road.